# How do Laser Feelings work?

Tags: lasers-and-feelings

During our game of [Lasers & Feelings](http://onesevendesign.com/lasers_and_feelings_rpg.pdf) we had a bit of a disagreement concerning how the special insight mechanic Laser Feelings works.

> If you roll your number exactly, you have laser feelings. You get a special insight into what's going on. Ask the GM a question and they’ll answer you honestly
>
> ...
>
> You can change your action if you want to, then roll again.

Our GM took this to mean that a player gets a single question **for each** exact matching roll, with the matching rolls counted as **fails** for the original roll and re-rolls permitted **only if the player changes action**.

This resulted in Laser Feelings questions being very abundant (the common 2d6 roll would yield at least one over 30% of the time) and also caused more failed rolls than I expected. We started going through the rules and noticed that the rules are quite ambiguous:

- "You can change your action if you want to, then roll again." Does this mean I can only scrap my original roll to re-roll if I change my action? Do I re-roll only the dice matching my number, or all dice? If I change my action, does my original action (and its roll) still apply?
- If I can't roll again without changing my action, are my matching rolls fails, successes or should they be re-rolled?
- Should I get two questions if I get two matching dice?

Answer (score 4):

The 1.3 version of Lasers and Feelings (which the link in the question now points to) explicitly says how to handle this situation:

> (A roll of LASER FEELINGS counts as a success.)

In previous versions of the rules, almost certainly including the ones that were current when this question was asked, this parenthetical sentence was not included, so there was some ambiguity. I think this was probably the best solution. It lets the player choose if they want to keep their success from their first roll, or change actions based on the extra information they learned asking the GM their question, and roll again.

For example, maybe a pirate captain has just beamed onto the bridge of the ship and is threatening the crew. Envoy McGee rolls Feelings to seduce the pirate, and gets *Laser Feelings*. They ask the GM what the pirate really wants and learn that they're madly in love with Captain Darcy and want to make sure they're OK. The Envoy could stick with their success, or change tactic and reroll, since seduction might not make as much sense given their new knowledge (though a space love triangle could also be dramatic).

Comment: also, there is no phrase "You can change your action if you want to, then roll again" in the current version of the rules

Answer (score 3):

If you roll your number you get a laser feeling which gives you the option to ask a question. Asking the question is usually in your best interest because you can choose to perform a different action based on the answer the GM supplies.

You only get one answer per action, not per die (if multiple dice match your number).

You might, or might not change your action. If you get an insight that suggests you could have taken a better action, then you may want to choose a different action, and re roll. If you get an insight that suggests your original action was the most appropriate or beneficial action, then you may choose to stick with the action.

If you rolled multiple dice because of being prepared or being an expert or getting an assist from another character, and at least one of those dice succeeded, then sticking with your current action may be fine. However, if all dice failed you now have a chance to try again with more information at your disposal.

If you change your action, then you only need to roll again if there is some degree of uncertainty or risk (uncertainty meaning probability of success < 1.0; risk is a state of uncertainty where at least one of the possible outcomes results in a loss of some sort). If you now have perfect information about the outcome based on the answer you got, you may not need to roll again. This is up to the GM.

If you change your action to another uncertain action and roll again, and then get laser feelings again (chain laser feelings) then you can ask another question, and so on. The idea here is to improve your information about the situation in order to maximize gains by reducing uncertainty and minimizing loss.

Or just have fun and wing it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the PDF you posted, consider the following:

> roll your dice and compare **each die** result to your number

Therefore I see it as you would get a number of questions equal to the dice matching the number.  Following standard loop procedure, and using the RAW explicitly, you can opt to change your action each time but a new roll would negate any further questions because it stops the the current roll cold.  Therefore, yes you can reroll with Laser Feelings but your new action may be worth less dice (not prepared or expert) so it may not be worth it, or the current action could be just as useful after insight.  So let's break this down...

- You would scrap the original roll and all effects for the new one because you're trying to achieve something different.  The original action is evaporated.  *"I was going to the fire the cannons but then I realized..."*
- Matching dice are fails.  It specifically says if the roll is *over* or *under* for its respective type, with equal being its own special exception.
- The way I see it, each die is compared so you get the extra questions as long as you don't change your action until the last one is asked; IE changing your action on the first question erases the other Laser Feeling di(c)e

Answer (score 2):

This is all strictly interpretation, but the way we have read it is:

If you roll Laser-Feelings, you:

- Get to ask 1 question per die of Laser-Feelings
- Then have the option of changing your action.  If you do, the whole process starts over again and old results are irrelevant.
- If you don't change your action, you re-roll your Laser-Feelings dice.

It all depends on whether you feel the "then roll again" clause is dependent on the "You may change your action if you want to" clause.  My view is that you can change your action if you want to, but either way, you roll again (just the L-F dice if sticking with your original action, all dice if you changed, because the whole roll may have changed.)

Answer (score -3):

The way I have always ruled it in games is that matching your number counts as a successful die roll and gives you a question. I also allow the effect to stack. Lasers and feelings is, at least in the way I have run it, a light game where a good story comes first.

Comment: This is catching a lot of down votes without comment. While I'm unfamiliar on the system, this posed answer appears to be in-line with the very brief rules that this system provides.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. The answer would likely be improved by citing the rules (whether to point out how your ruling is supported by the rules, or even just to say the rules don't address this and that's why you ruled in this way) before presenting your own ruling on the matter. You should also elaborate on how this ruling has worked out in practice; has it caused any problems, and are there any other issues to be aware of when ruling in this way?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical "this is how I ruled it" does not *actually* answer the question "how does this rule work?". This being a Q&A, non-answers tend to be downvoted. If C4Dragon follows V2Blast's suggestions, then his post would become proper answer to the question