# When does "Goblin Magic" happen?

Tags: magic, goblin-court

I'm exploring some rules-light RPGs, and am intrigued by "[Goblin Court v2](https://besw.itch.io/goblin-court)" by [BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw?tab=profile) (though I haven't played it yet). I'm confused by the wording on how "Goblin Magic" happens. If some dice succeed and some dice cause Goblin Magic, what happens?

Just to make this concrete example, suppose my Magic Number is 3, and the GM has me roll Compassion with three dice (because it's something I do a lot and another goblin is helping me), and I get 1, 3, and 6. It looks like under "Dice Outcomes", both Rule 1 (one die succeeded) and Rule 4 (I rolled the Magic Number exactly) would apply. I would kind of naively think that just both things would happen (I get a "barely manage" success and I also get to ask the Goblin Mom a question), but then it says that when I get Goblin Magic it doesn't resolve the action and I reroll. So does that mean that if I get any die matching the Magic Number, then none of the other dice matter and I reroll the whole thing?

Again, since I haven't played it (and I haven't played much in the way of rules-light RPGs at all) I'm probably greatly misunderstanding something. It's just confusing to me that an otherwise-successful roll would be negated by the Goblin Magic, and it seems like it would happen a lot in any cases where one was rolling several dice.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate!), since Goblin Court is a drift of Lasers & Feelings: ["How do Laser Feelings work?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51751/4398)

Answer (score 5):

Note that the comparisons to your number are *per die*.

That means that you have a failure, you have a success, and you have an-

***interruption: Goblin Magic!***

The die on which you rolled your number triggers Goblin Magic. You ask your question, you get your answer, and you reroll *that die.*

***[end interruption]***

Now you've got a third (let's assume) non-Goblin Magic roll to compare to your number.

---

Two edge-cases:

**1. The reroll triggers Goblin Magic.** Ask a question, get an answer, re-roll again.

**2. You decide to change your action (based on Goblin Magic info).** The whole roll gets gathered up, Goblin Mom helps you decide how many dice to roll for *this* action, and the resolution loop starts anew.